# Problems changing values in an array/object nested combination array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know what to do to get this done what would like to do. I tried multiple approaches, e.g. I used `array_map`, `array_walk`, nested `foreach` loops with `get_object_vars` and I worked with `json_decode/encode` and so on. I always come a little bit further but never reach my goal and I would like to get some guidance from you

Basically when you see the array below, how would you proceed when you want to change some value in the `path` array for multiple values in the array itself?

**My questions:**

1) Is it right that I must convert both nested objects to an array first or is this not nesessary to do this? I mean I always get some type conversion error which tells me that I either have everything as an object or array. Is this right?

2) If this mistery is solved, which php array function is the appropriate one to change values in an array(/object)? As I have written above, I tried so many and I don't see the trees in the woods anymore. Which one do you suggest to me to use in a foreach loop?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bob
                            [1] => pictures
                            [2] => food
                        )
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (

                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Alice
                            [1] => pictures
                            [2] => vacations
                            [3] => rome
                        )
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Give a sample output of what you want to achieve.

Comment: for example to change "Bob" to "Bobby", you can write `$arr[0]->doc->path[0] = "Bobby";`. What do you want else?

Comment: explain `"change some value in the path array for **multiple values**"`

Comment: You can access path array by using for/foreach loop. And what do you mean by  'want to change some value in the path array'. can you give some sample output.

Comment: you tried lots but don't want to show?? How can we fix it then?

Comment: @Salketer I don't show my try and error code because it would befuddle people. This is the only reason.

Comment: @TahaPaksu The thing is that for example "Bob" is searched for and should be replaced at every occurrence. So it hast to be dynamically.

Comment: @RavinderReddy Let's say the path changes, than every occurrence of "pictures" has to be changes to "pics" for example.

Comment: @Magiranu the problem is that you'll never know what you did wrong... You'll just end up copy/pasting a generic answer... But that really is up to you, I give you that.

Comment: @Salketer This is totally right. Maybe you can see that I don't ask for specific code but rather for some sort of guidance. Maybe it's not clear enough. I don't know :(

Comment: @Magiranu I get that, but you said you tried array_map, array_walk and foreach, while they are all possible solutions. To answer both your questions straight: 1- NO, 2- Depends on implementation, but array_walk, array_map and foreach could do. See, you won't get much further with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that,

1. you create an array with keys as new path and value as old path (
   path to be replaced).
2. Loop you path array and check if it is available in above defined array.
3. If available replace it with key of above defined array.

For example

```
// array defined as point 1
$change_path_array= array('pics'=>'pictures','meal'=>'food');
// $array is your array.
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // loop you path array  
    for($i=0;$i<count($value->doc->path);$i++){
        // check if the value is in defined array
        if(in_array($value->doc->path[$i],$change_path_array)){
            // get the key and replace it. 
            $value->doc->path[$i] = array_search($value->doc->path[$i], $change_path_array);
        }
    }
}
```

Out Put: picture is replaced with pics and food with meal

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bob
                            [1] => pics
                            [2] => meal
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [doc] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Alice
                            [1] => pics
                            [2] => vacations
                            [3] => rome
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

You can modify the code to check casesensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $path_array = $arr[$i]->doc->path;
    // do your modifications for [i]th path element
    // in your case replace all 'Bob's with 'Joe's
    $path_array = array_map(function($paths){
        if($paths == 'Bob') return 'Joe';
        return $paths;
    }, $paths_array);

    $arr[$i]->doc->path = $path_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of changing all `pictures` to `photos`:

```
$doc1 = new \stdClass;
$doc1->doc = new \stdClass;
$doc1->doc->path = array('Bob', 'pictures', 'food');

$doc2 = new \stdClass;
$doc2->doc = new \stdClass;
$doc2->doc->path = array('Alice', 'pictures', 'vacations', 'rome');

$documents = array($doc1, $doc2);

/* change all 'pictures' to 'photos' */
foreach ($documents as &$doc) {
    foreach ($doc->doc->path as &$element) {
        if ($element == 'pictures') {
            $element = 'photos';
        }
        unset($element);
    }
    unset($doc);
}
print_r($documents);
```